# WKWebView how to disable adjustedContentInset when keyboard is shown?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

If I open the keyboard when displaying a WKWebView it automatically adds adjustedContentInset to the ScrollView. But the problem is, if I handle the keyboard myself it still adds the adjustedContentInset. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you remove the observers which handles the keyboard from the WKWebView it stops adding the adjustedContentInset:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.webView, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.webView, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.webView, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: awesome, how did you come to this solution? I tried everything trying to remove this  inset at bottom after manual webview frame change, only this solution helped

Comment: @schmidt9 honestly I tried a lot of stuff that didn't work. Eventually thought maybe it also uses the keyboard notification. And luckily it did!

Comment: It is 2023 now and it still works for me on iOS 16. Genius solution...Just hope Apple doesn't change the internal method how it observer the keyboard.

Comment: OMG you are my saviour

Comment: Very nice solution. Unfortunately that also disables the scrollview content offset adjustment so that the web control getting the focus is centered and obstructed by the keyboard.

Comment: @GregdeJ That tracks, but you can just offset those yourself by observing the same notifications right?

Comment: @AdamKaplan Yes, that's why I wanted them gone, because I needed to handle them myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue when changing the auto layout constraints on a web view when `keyboardWillShowNotification`/`keyboardWillHideNotification` fires.

What worked for me:

1. Instantiate `WKWebView` *AFTER* adding the observers on keyboard events.
2. After changing the auto layout constraints, trigger a layout phase.

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

notificationCenter.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
  .sink { [weak self] _ in
    self?.attachWebViewToKeyboard()
    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
  .store(in: &cancellables)

notificationCenter.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
  .sink { [weak self] _ in
    self?.attachWebViewToBounds()
    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
  .store(in: &cancellables)

webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
```

(I'm using Combine here but classic `addObserver` works too.)

The upvoted solution also works, but the downside is it also disables the automatic scroll content offset adjustment when an `<input>` element gets focus and opens the keyboard.