# Extra space on WKWebView when keyboard is opened

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am resizing the webview when keyboard is opened. I added some debug styling for webview like this

```
self.webViewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 5
self.webViewController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
self.webViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

example here: https://github.com/zecar/ios-app-clone

[image]

This is what i'm getting after opening the keyboard
The resize seems to work ok, i have the green border around webview so that's good. The problem is the blue background that is showing and it seems to have the exact height as the keyboard.

This is how I'm doing the resizing

```
self.keyboardOpenedFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.5, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.originalFrame.height - kbSize)
self.view.frame = self.keyboardOpenedFrame
```

The HTML element you are seeing at the top is a fullscreen element with fixed positioning and 100% height 100% width so I guess the blue margin is not added inside the HTML page.

Any ideas?

//edit: add webview struct

```
struct WebView: View {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            WebViewRepresentable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            WebViewRepresentable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
    
    struct WebViewRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WebView.WebViewRepresentable>) -> UIViewController {

            return WebViewController()
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WebView.WebViewRepresentable>) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using UIViewRepresentable( SwiftUI ) or UIKit ?

Comment: UIViewRepresentable yes

Comment: did you try this   .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)

Comment: @Yodagama i have WebViewRepresentable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe you could try loading a different webView link and try seeing if the blue still shows when opening the keyboard. That way you can distinguish wether it's a problem with the website, or just the webview code :)

Comment: And it'll also be good if you could share the code that's inside the `makeUIView` function

Comment: @Amy added the makeUIViewController function; also tried with another html file, same thing

Comment: @John, is that reproducible example? Try to copy-paste these pieces of code into new project and run... and you'll see what we see. Do you really need help?

Comment: @Asperi https://github.com/zecar/ios-app-clone i managed to do the example here

Comment: @John the github project is empty project, make sure you uploaded the right one

Comment: @FaizanYousaf updated, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the content inset of WKWebView's ScrollView:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
        self.webViewController.wv.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 - keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    }
}
```

And

```
@objc func keyboardWillHideß(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.webViewController.wv.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    })
}
```

Comment: well yes.. but this part that calculates the keyboard height is already working.. the issue is that there is extra content added at the bottom of the webview

Comment: Please check the edit and see if changing content inset of the scrollview works!

Comment: it did not work.. what worked was leaving the frame resize and setting bottom: 0 - keyboardHeight on the edge insets :/ is this even the best way?

Comment: i edited your answer and added relevant info inside so i can mark it

Answer (score 1):

The top voted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136482/wkwebview-how-to-disable-adjustedcontentinset-when-keyboard-is-shown) gives the way to disable WkWebView's keyboard handling.
The answer is amazingly simple.
Just remove these observations of the WKWebView instance. It works for me on iOS 16.

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.webView, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.webView, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.webView, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

I guess it's just how WKWebView internally observers keyboard changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to calculate keyboard frame manually, because it is handled by constraints to show textfield with keyboard, so just comment

```
//        self.keyboardOpenedFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.5, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.originalFrame.height - kbSize)
        
//        print("[LOG] SETTING FRAME \(self.keyboardOpenedFrame)")
//        self.view.frame = self.keyboardOpenedFrame
```

and result behavior is correct (frame should not be changed here - keyboard offset is handled internally show correct relative position of TextField)

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: but it is not because the content is just pushed up, i need the window to resize so the content inside is smaller.. so 100% height with keyboard opened will be smaller than 100% with keyboard closed. So if i have a chat header at the top and the input at the bottom, when keyboard is opened the header should still be at the top, not pushed up like it is without the resizing of frame

Comment: WKWebView is-a UIScrollView, so who'd guaranty that when you change frame it will not scroll up just because content does not fit? But it is of course up to you. And btw ... it is you added that extra space, because WKWebView handles keyboard by itself, and you just duplicate that... so extra is there.

Comment: think of it this way: you have a chat window that is 100% height (let's say 800px for simplicity). at the top you have the header, at the bottom you have the text input and in the middle is the messages list. Now the keyboard is opened (let's say it has 300px height). In order for my chat window to maintain its aspect, it would have to be resized to 500px so we still have header-messages-input in the viewport. Right now it's resizing the webview to 500px but somehow adds the 500px inside of it. i don't want it to push the content because i am resizing the window already, no need to push

Comment: WKWebview handles the keyboard by pushing the content upwards. I need it to stop doing that